# Why is SQL Server procedure reading Guid as character string?

Tags: sql-server

I have this stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[_Doc_GetDoc]
    @Id uniqueidentifier
AS  
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RetVal INT,
            @TranCount INT

BEGIN TRY
    IF (ISNUll(@Id, '') = '')
        RETURN 1002
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT .....
        FROM Documents WITH (nolock)        
        WHERE Documents.Id = @Id 
          AND ISNULL(Documents.IsDeleted, 0) = 0

        SET @RetVal = 1
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT error_message()
    SET @RetVal= 9999   
END CATCH

RETURN @RetVal
END
```

When I run it like this:

```
USE [xxxxxxxx]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[_Doc_GetDoc]
        @Id = 6666a6c6-6666-e966-67a9-a5bf52222d44

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near '6666a6c6'.

If I pass the `@Id` in single quotes it says `Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier`

I tried:

```
exec [dbo].[_Doc_GetDocument] '6666a6c6-6666-e966-67a9-a5bf52222d44'
exec [dbo].[_Doc_GetDocument] @DocId='6666a6c6-6666-e966-67a9-a5bf52222d44'
```

But same error: Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

Comment: What is the data-type of `Documents.Id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fail is here:

```
  if(ISNUll(@Id,'')='')
```

If you pass a quote quote argument to isnull, the input (1st argument) will be treated as string. Try this instead:

edit:

```
if @Id IS NULL
```

More, i noticed your `alter procedure` is calling `[dbo].[_Doc_GetDoc]`, but you try to execute `exec [dbo].[_Doc_GetDocument]`. Make sure u're calling the right one, and use squares instead of quotes for your ID parameter:

```
exec [dbo].[_Doc_GetDoc] [6666a6c6-6666-e966-67a9-a5bf52222d44]
```

Comment: Nope error : Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure _Doc_GetDoc, Line 18 [Batch Start Line 7]
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier

Comment: right, you cant treat a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` column as int. i've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

The uniqueidentifier data type has a higher [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) than character types so a SQL Server will attempt to convert the character value to uniqueidentifier during this comparison operation:

```
where Documents.Id=@Id
```

The operation will fail with the conversion error if the `Id` column contains a value that can't be converted. For example:

```
SELECT 'oops' 
WHERE CAST('6666a6c6-6666-e966-67a9-a5bf52222d44' AS uniqueidentifier) = 'foobar';
```

So it seems you have invalid GUID string values in the table. The best practices is to change the column data type to `uniqueidentifier` to avoid the problem going forward. That will require existing bad data to be remediated.